# Docker container eating space over time in my EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, hasura

I've installed only Hasura and a Postgres database (yes yes, I'll change it) in 1 docker container each. The containers themselves don't use much space, but my overall storage space is rapidly being used up each passing day! I have no idea why, I'm pretty new to this.

Using Ubuntu 16.0.4 in AWS EC2.

Results of **docker ps as**

```
015ff0c04b91        hasura/graphql-engine:v2.2.1   "graphql-engine serve"   11 days ago         Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   ubuntu_graphql-engine_1         
 0B (virtual 395MB)
b79e1cfd6c3e        postgres:12                    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 weeks ago         Up 11 days          0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   b79e1cfd6c3e_ubuntu_postgres_1  
 135B (virtual 373MB)
```

Results of : **docker system df**

```
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              2                   2                   767.5MB             0B (0%)
Containers          2                   2                   135B                0B (0%)
Local Volumes       1                   1                   193.8MB             0B (0%)
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

Results of **df -h**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            992M     0  992M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M   21M  179M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1       20G   15G  4.6G  77% /
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15177
/dev/loop1       44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14978
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop3       25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
/dev/loop4       27M   27M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5163
/dev/loop5       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2344
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Results of : **sudo du -x -h / | sort -h | tail -10**

```
343M/usr/bin
444M/usr/lib
783M/var/lib/docker/overlay2
1.2G/usr
12G/var/lib/docker/containers
12G/var/lib/docker/containers/015ff0c04b91075472bceeb30f0fac1ef0e7b50518241047138a6d184b2897df
13G/var/lib/docker
14G/var
14G/var/lib
15G/
```

Results of **docker info**

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 2
Server Version: 18.09.7
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
```

**docker-compose** file

```
networks:
 wdnetwork:
  driver: bridge
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    networks:
    - wdnetwork
    environment:
POSTGRES_USER: xxx
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxx
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.2.1
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    links:
    - postgres:postgres
    depends_on:
    - "postgres"
    networks:
    - wdnetwork
    restart: always
    environment:
from here, its irrelevant hasura stuff(password, links etc)
```

results of **du -h | sort -h | tail -n5** after exec -it into the graphql container. Similar results for other container as well

```
78M./usr/bin
99M./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
168M./usr/lib
297M./usr
362M.
```

I've already attempted:

- `docker system prune` (0B reclaimed)
- `docker restart`
- `docker-compose up detach build`

No effect on reducing storage space.

Comment: A few days ago, when I restarted the EC2 instance, it had magically shrunk back to only 2.2GB used and the app was fine with all data in it. Which confirms that its definitely not there any actual usage but logs/containers using space unnecessarily. And it keeps climbing rapidly everyday!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please add the output of `docker system df` to the question?

Comment: You may get better answers on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Hey thanks @ErmiyaEskandary ! I have added docker system df as well.

Comment: Does the same happen locally? Do those containers have any volumes? Can you please share your `docker-compose` file?

Comment: Given that you have 12 GB in one container, it would appear that something is writing into the container's filesystem, probably a logfile. It appears (from the container hashes) that it's the graphql container. I don't know what that image looks like, but if it includes `bash` you can run an interactive session with `docker run -it CONTAINER /bin/bash` (replacing `CONTAINER` with the running container hash). Then you can use `df` and `du` to try to figure out what's going on inside the container's filesystem (assuming that they've been installed -- some images don't).

Comment: In general, if you're using a container you should configure logging to write to `stderr`, which is captured by Docker (as is `stdout`) and can be directed somewhere else with a [logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/).

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - I have added the docker-compose file to the post now

Comment: @Parsifal - I've gone into the container and ran du and updated post with results.

Comment: Is the container currently consuming a large amount of host disk space (ie, is the container's directory in `/var/lib/docker/containers/` multiple gigabytes?) If not, then you're going to have to wait until the container shows signficant growth before running `du`.

Comment: If it _is_ consuming large amounts of host space, and that space is not accounted-for by running `du` (which appears to be the case), then it means that something created a file and immediately deleted it while keeping it open (this is often used for temporary files). You can use `lsof` to identify such files, although I would have to look at the man page to tell you how (which is something that you can do yourself).